# parsing web service with the hierarchy parameters in xml schema

Tags: xml, web-services, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, query-designer

i need to get data from web service via reporting services.
the xml schema i got showing structure as follow:

```
........
<element name="methodname">
<complextype>
<sequence>
<element name="prm-in">
<complextype>
<element name="prm1" type="decimal">
<element name="prm2" type="decimal">
.......
</sequence>
</complextype>
</element>
```

how can i retrieve data from this schema via the query designer of the ssrs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
<Query>
<Method Name=methodname Namespace=somenamespace >
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="prm-in" Type="xml">
<DefaultValue>
<prm1>11</prm1>
<prm2>22</prm2>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
```